# 2-pass ratecontrol in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use 2pass ratecontrol in 2nd pass mode in FFmpeg but I don't know the proper command. I've seen these been used `-flags`, `-input_preserved` and `-pass2` in ffmpeg documentation but I don't how to use them (If I need to use these anyway). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're using libx264 to encode H.264 video. The most basic command is something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 800k -pass 1 output.mp4
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 800k -pass 2 output.mp4
```

However, it can be improved:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 800k -an -pass 1 -f mp4 /dev/null
ffmpeg -y -i input -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 800k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -pass 2 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- The audio should not need to be encoded for the first pass, so `-an` is added to the first pass command.
- The first pass does not need to output a video file, so it is directed to `/dev/null/`. Windows users can use `NUL` instead.
- 2-passes with libx264 is usually used if you are targeting a specific output file size (`file size = bitrate * duration`). If this is not the utmost concern to you then **just use a single pass with `-crf` instead**.
- Use the slowest `-preset` you have patience for.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info including how to get the file size you want.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your answer! Second, what exactly `-movflags +faststart` does and why is it better? And what are  `input_preserved` and `pass2`? Also I read FFmpeg wiki that the `-an` will not work in many cases.

Comment: @KLNy `-movflags +faststart` will move some info to the beginning of the file after encoding completes so if the video is being viewed via progressive download it can begin playback more quickly; otherwise the complete file must be downloaded before playback may begin. I've never used the `-flags` options you listed. IIRC, there is a bug report involving `-an` when using 2-passes with libx264, but I do not believe I have ever encountered that issue (but I almost never use 2-passes).